# Loop Variables and `unset` in Shell Script

Tags: shell, loops, unset

I just wanted to confirm here since I've only tested in `dash` shell, but do loop variables collide with variables in the outer scope in shell scripts in general? For example

```
#! /bin/sh

i='1 2 3'
a='a b c'

for i in $a; do
  echo "$i"
done

echo "$i"
```

This outputs:

```
a
b
c
c
```

which makes sense to me. That is, it seems to indicate that I'm right that loop variables will collide (they share the same namespace as the outer scope). I want to know because if I'm using an older-style shell that doesn't have the `local` command, I want to be sure to `unset` loop variables I use in functions. The texts I've read cover `unset`, but don't seem to cover this case.

Am I right?

Comment: In the way your script is written it's ( the loop ) not forked in a sub-shell -- So yes the name spaces will collide.

Comment: @Zak Thanks! How would i make the above example not collide and still print to the parent shell stdout?

Comment: BTW, note that `for i in $a` is itself an antipattern. The correct way to store lists of things is with an array-type variable. That is, `a=( a b c )`, then `for i in "${a[@]}"`; that way you can iterate over lists of strings even when those individual strings can contain spaces or be interpreted as globs.

Comment: For example, let's say you had `a='Hello[world] Goodbye'` -- if there's a file named `Helloo` or `Hellod` in the directory where the script is run, those filenames would be substituted into `$i` instead of the literal `Hello[world]` string. Whereas `a=( 'Hello[world]' 'Goodbye' )` and `for i in "${a[@]}"` will assign _exactly_ `Hello[world]` no matter what filenames exist.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's only true for shells that support arrays. Consider ksh88 and older versions of Bourne-Style shells. In this case, it is not an antipattern. I don't want to use arrays here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You to avoid namespace issues .. You can fork your script and put the loop inside that fork ..

```
#! /bin/sh

i='1 2 3'
a='a b c'

function_to_fork(){
  for i in $a; do
     echo "$i"
  done
}

(function_to_fork)

echo "$i"
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true. A subprocess would wait for the function to finish. Alternatively, we could capture the PID with `?!` and use `wait` before running `echo "$i"`

Comment: Correct, `foo & wait $!` is (almost) effectively equivalent to `(foo)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see your point .. But is `wait` necessary if we use `(function_to_fork)` instead?

Comment: Strike that .. Your comment was hidden .. Noted, and edited ..

Answer (score 1):

First: Yes, in all POSIX-compliant shells, variables are global by default, and loops do not have their own scope.

To prevent variables you use from escaping to global context, encapsulate the usage in a function with a `local` declaration, as follows:

```
i='1 2 3'
a='a b c'

yourfunc() {
  local i             # <- here, we make i function-local
  for i in $a; do     # aside: don't use unquoted expansions like this
     echo "$i"
  done
}

yourfunc
echo "$i"
```

...and `$i` is no longer overwritten.

---

`local` is not part of the POSIX sh specification, but it's such a widely-honored extension that even ash and dash provide it.

Comment: Thank you, but I am supporting older versions of Bourne-style shells where `local` is unavailable. Instead, I would use `unset` in this instance. The option of running the process in the background as @Zak suggested will work for me though.

Comment: `yourfunc &` is a very bad idea. Really do use `(yourfunc)` instead.

Comment: I'll bite. Why do you think it is a bad idea?